# Implement arguments of a function in a loop

Tags: c, loops

How would I implement a function with its arguments changing in a loop?

i.e. I would like to be able to implement the function in the form:

```
f( A[0], A[1], A[2] );
f( A[2], A[0], A[1] );
f( A[1], A[2], A[0] );
f( A[0], A[1], A[2] );
f( A[2], A[0], A[1] );
f( A[1], A[2], A[0] );
```

I got as far as being able to create the numbers in the correct place with the program below, tested using the printf() function:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, k, l;

    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for( j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
        {
            for( k = 0; k < 3; k++ )
            {
                l = k - j;
                if( l < 0)
                    l += 3;
                printf("%d", l);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear, what you're asking? Do you want to implement `f` or do you want code that *calls* `f` with cyclic permutations of the arguments?

Comment: You'll find it much easier to generate a cyclic permutation like that using the modulus operator (`%`). That said, it is not clear what you mean by *"be able to implement the function in the form"*. Care to clarify?

Comment: @ExP yes I want to call f with cyclic permutations, so that rather than writing the top block of code (in my actual program it would significantly more than 6 lines), I can write it as a loop.

Comment: @dmckee could you give an example of an implementation using % please?

Comment: I ought to make you discover it for yourself, but `for(int i=0; i<2*N; i+=2) f( A[i%3], A[(i+1)%3], A[(i+2)%3]);` The gymnastics with the `2`s are because you are getting the permutations "backwards". Now figure out how to do it with arbitrary cycles.

Comment: As an alternative to using the factors of two you could use a decrementing loop, but you'll need to be sure to align the first iteration.

Comment: @dmckee Thank you for the guidance, I can see how that works now! Definitely a much more elegant solution than my own :) If you add it as the answer I can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, all you need is:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < NUM_CALLS; i++)
    f(A[(2 * i) % 3], A[(2 * i + 1) % 3], A[(2 * i + 2) % 3])
```

Comment: Well, he wants the permutations backwards. See my comment on the main question.

Comment: the answer you give will not call f with the order that the OP provide in his question

Answer (score 0):

All you're missing is `f( A[i], A[j], A[k] );` in the inner-most loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the example given, it appears that you wish to loop through three (3) permutations of A[0], A[1] and A[2].

The simplest way, which might not be what you are looking for is to do ...

```
for (i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; i++)
    {
    f (A[0], A[1], A[2]);
    f (A[2], A[0], A[1]);
    f (A[1], A[2], A[0]);
    }
```

Someone else, I believe has already listed an algorithm using the modulus operator '%' so I will skip that.  You may also wish to use a predefined array.  Consider ...

```
ArgumentArray[6] = {A[0], A[1], A[2], A[0], A[1]};

for (i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; i++)
    {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
        f (ArgumentArray[j], ArgumentArray[j+1], ArgumentArray[j+2]);
        }
    }
```

Granted, the above does not give you the same order of calling f() that you posted in your question, but it may be helpful in giving you new ideas about which way you want to proceed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I wouldn't use the these in my case as there are a lot more functions being used cyclically (I simplified it for the sake of the question :) ).

Answer (score 0):

I can remark that the indices are circular shifted in the right each time. so here after what I can suggest to you

```
void indices_circular_right_shift(int *indices) {
    // The indices are circular rught shifted
    int k = indices[2];
    indices[2] = indices[1];
    indices[1] = indices[0];
    indices[0] = k;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    int indices[3] = {0, 1, 2};
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
        f(A[indices[0]], A[indices[1]], A[indices[2]]);
        indices_circular_right_shift(indices);
    }

}
```

Comment: Another unnecessarily complicated way to make this happen.

Comment: @dmckee you are right the solution you provide in your comment is more simple comparing to mine. please adde it as answer and I will delete mine